# Programmatically assign NULL to certain columns for certain rows when unioning datasets

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out a way to programmatically assign `NULL` to certain columns for certain rows when unioning 2 datasets together.  This is most easily explained using an example.  The rows in `#stage2` need to display NULL in columns `cost_center3`, `cost_center14` in the final dataset.  The code below works but it is a manual approach and not dynamic if more cost_center columns need to be added.

```
select *
into #stage1
from
(
    values
    (42, 170, 44, 827),
    (43, 170, 68, 880),
    (44, 190, 31, 745)
) d (work_center, plant, cost_center3, cost_center14);

select *
into #stage2
from
(
    values
    (10, 200),
    (11, 200),
    (12, 200)
) d (work_center, plant);

--manual approach - need to find a programmatic way to do this
select * from #stage1
union
select *, NULL, NULL from #stage2;
```

[image]

In the actual business use case, there are several more cost_center columns than are shown in this example - thus the need to find a way to programmatically do this task.

I have experimented with `CROSS APPLY` like this

```
select s1.*, s2.*
from #stage1 s1
cross apply #stage2 s2;
```

but it is essentially cross joining the datasets and that is not the desired outcome.

Can this task be done programmatically and concisely?

Comment: Programmatically yes, concisely no. T-SQL hates dynamic result sets and you'll have to resort to dynamic SQL for this. It's not going to be pretty. It would actually be slightly less painful to programmatically generate the `ALTER TABLE` statements necessary to add the missing columns to the other table, then `UNION ALL` it together.

Comment: How about just `insert`ing into a temp table and then `select`ing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using, even though the number of `NULL`s is not dynamic:

```
select * from #stage1
union
select * from #stage2 cross join (values (null, null)) d (cost_center4, cost_center14);
```